# Jquery clearing content

Tags: jquery

I have got the following Jquery code and an html page that contains some buttons with numbers 1- 2 -3-4-5-6 and a clear button, how do i clear the numbers once I have typed them.

I tried selecting the clear button by id but that does not work as I am selecting all buttons in this code.

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
     var txt = $(this).val();
     $('#textbox').val( $('#textbox').val() + txt ); 
});
```

Comment: I am not getting what actually you are trying to do .

Comment: So you append the button value to an input and then you want to revert back to what the input value was originally?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" id="btnClear" value="Clear" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#btnClear').click(function() {
    $('#textbox').val(''); 
});
```

Also change your code like,

```
$('input[type="button"]:not(#btnClear)').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#textbox').val( $('#textbox').val() + txt ); 
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the :btnClear please?

Comment: See my `answer` once **again**, in this I've added a `HTML button` whose `id` is `btnClear`.

Answer (score 0):

give your clear button an id (unique) and use id selector...and `.val('')` to clear

```
 $('#clearButtonID').click(function() {
      $('#textbox').val(''); 
  });
```

and you can name rest of the buttons with same class and use class selector for other button..

```
 $('.otherButtonsClassName').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#textbox').val( $('#textbox').val() + txt ); 
  });
```

else use not..

```
 $('input[type="button"]').not('#clearButtonID').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#textbox').val( $('#textbox').val() + txt ); 
 });
```

Comment: `.not` `Remove elements from the set of matched elements.` that means the selector `$('input[type="button"]')` selects all buttons and `.not('#clearButtonID')` removes the element with id `clearButtonID` which is the clear button in your case. so   `$('input[type="button"]').not('#clearButtonID')` selects all button exept the clear button... http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 0):

give your clear button an `id` eg `clear` and your text field an id too eg. `txt`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#clear').bind('click',function(){
       $('#txt').val("");   
   });
});
```